# I cannot make the dialog pop up to appear when clicked on the link from appended listview

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using this swipe to delete function from this page:
https://github.com/ksloan/jquery-mobile-swipe-list

The challenge that I am facing is that in this example, the `ul` list is appended by using ajax. I managed to include the anchor tag within the call like this:

```
$('#myPostsList').append('<li class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="listIcon" ><div class="behind"><a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-btn delete-btn">Delete</a></div><a href="" data-myProfile='+item.myUserProfileID+' data-key='+item.myrandomPostId+'><img class="feedImage" src='+item.myPic+'></img><p><strong>'+item.myName+", "+item.myGender+'</p></strong>'
                                                 + '<p>'+item.myPost+'<p>'

                                                 + '<p class="ui-li-aside" ><time class="timeago" datetime='+item.myTime+'></time></p></a></li>'
                                                 );

                                }

                                });
```

As you can see, I have added `a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="dialog"`. However when I click the button, it won't show the dialog box, and instead takes me to another page.

in HTML:

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="myPopupDialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Delete post?</h1>
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this post?</h3>
                <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                <a href="#page-messages" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-     inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
                <a href="#page-messages" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!---------Popup to delete post------------>
```

Any hint/help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Replace dialog with popup. `data-role="popup"` and in anchor, `data-rel="popup"`.

Comment: @Omar Thanks Omar, but is not working.

Comment: Is the popup div outside page div?

Comment: Hi again @Omar, yes the div that contains the popup is within a page.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to make this work in this particular case, the popup needs to be nested within the page but outside the `<div data-role="content"`